# How to add parameter to Telerik Report Source?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, telerik-reporting

I have added the Telerik Report Viewer to my windows form and set the report source as `ConsignmentReport.Report1, ConsignmentReport, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`. `ConsignmentReport` is my telerik report designer class. My datasource for the designer is MySql and my sql query needs a parameter. I've set the connection string, data provider, query and parameter in the designer and everything works correctly in the designer preview. My parameter name is @jsno

Then, I tried to add the parameter for the ReportViewer like this

```
reportViewer1.ReportSource.Parameters[0].Value = "19020312";
```

and it did not work.

Also tried to add like this

```
reportViewer1.ReportSource.Parameters.add(new Telerik.Reporting.Parameter("@jsno","19020312"));
```

Also did not work.
My report viewer remains blank. When tried to remove the parameter from the query and just run the report viewer with simple select statement, the report is generated. So how could I add the parameter to the report source?

Answer (score 0):

The report source parameters enable passing values to the [report parameters](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports-parameters). So, you need to first add a report parameter to the report definition, in order to be able to pass a value from the report source. On the other hand, you have the data source component which has its own parameters. To bind the data source parameter to the report parameter, do set the following expression as a value of the data source parameter: `=Parameters.jsno`

Then, at runtime to pass a concrete parameter value to the report, use the second snippet:

```
reportViewer1.ReportSource.Parameters.add(new Telerik.Reporting.Parameter("@jsno","19020312"));
```

More info at [Using Parameters with the SqlDataSource component](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/sql-data-source-using-parameters) (You can use the designer to make the setup)